# SQL server table not locating the respective Record ID

Tags: salesforce-id, sqlserver

My SQL server administrator could establish a connection with our salesforce sandbox instance and could bulk insert brand new records. However, he couldn't update the existing records as the record ID is not available in the table.

We are getting the following error when we tried to update the records with the name:

> Error: 0xC002F304 at Stores-Staging-Target, SF_Store [2]: An error
>   occurred with the following error message: "(1) Id not specified in an
>   update call [STATUS: MISSING_ARGUMENT]".Error: 0xC02090F9 at
>   Stores-Staging-Target, SF_Store [2]: The SF_Store was unable to
>   process the data.Error: 0xC0047022 at Stores-Staging-Target,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "SF_Store" (2) failed with error code
>   0xC02090F9 while processing input "Salesforce Destination Input" (15).
>   The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput
>   method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal
>   and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: The only string which makes sense to me is "`STATUS: MISSING_ARGUMENT`"

Comment: Me too.  I am not a sql administrator and my colleague is not a salesforce administrator. This has been a big challenge for both of us.

Comment: `Id not specified in an update call`

Comment: I got it! ID is not in the records you want to update

Comment: Check with the SQL administrator if they are sending the Salesforce record ID.  However, I don't know how you are updating records.

Comment: You could create external id field in salesforce side. To store your sql server Id.

Comment: @llya lepesh: the problem is the ID field is formula field on salesforce.